A probability involving side lengths of a random triangle on a disk: Is it really $\frac37$?
Choose three uniformly random points on a disk, and let them be the vertices of a triangle. Call the side lengths, in random order, $a,b,c$.


What is $P(a^2<bc)$ ?

A simulation with $10^7$ such random triangles yielded a proportion of $0.4285833\approx1.00003\times\frac{3}{7}$ satisfying $a^2<bc$, leading me to believe that the probability is $\frac37$.
I find this alleged probability interesting because it seems that the number $7$ rarely appears in the answers to natural geometry or probability questions.
Context
Recently I have learned that some probabilities related to circles, of the form $P(x^2<yz)$, have simple rational values (for example, a probability about a random triangle inscribed in a circle, and a probability about a random pentagram inscribed in a circle). So I wondered if there is a probability like this related to a disk. I may have found one.
My attempt
Let the boundary of the disk be $x^2+y^2=1$.
Using disk point picking, let the three points be

$C\left(\sqrt{r_1}\cos\theta_1,\sqrt{r_1}\sin\theta_1\right)$
$B\left(\sqrt{r_2}\cos\theta_2,\sqrt{r_2}\sin\theta_2\right)$
$A\left(\sqrt{r_3},0\right)$

where each $r$ is a uniformly random real number from $0$ to $1$, and each $\theta$ is a uniformly random real number from $0$ to $2\pi$.
Let $a=BC$, $b=AC$, $c=AB$.
This gives:
$$P(a^2<bc)=P\left(r_1+r_2-2\sqrt{r_1r_2}\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)<\sqrt{\left(r_1-2\sqrt{r_1r_3}\cos\theta_1+r_3\right)\left(r_2-2\sqrt{r_2r_3}\cos\theta_2+r_3\right)}\right)$$
I do not know how to set up an integral, nor any other way to calculate the probability. Apparently, after the dust settles, we should be left with $\frac37$.

$bc=a(\frac{h_a}{\sin{A}})$ (this derives from law of sines), so you may get some traction by considering your question in the form of $P(a<\frac{h_a}{\sin{A}})$.

There are three ways to choose the largest side. Extending the lines of the triangle partitions the circle into 7 regions.

@vallev But if the vertices of the triangle are random points in a square lamina, the probability seems to be very different, about $0.73$.

Can you clarify why the y-coordinate of your point A is set to zero? It appears to be chosen not uniformly at random, which may be causing the discrepancy.

well I tried editing the question twice to correct it but it got rejected by reviewers

@vallev After we choose the first random point, we can rotate the disk about its centre so that the first random point's $y$-coordinate is zero. Then we can choose the other four random points. So we can assume that the first random point's $y$-coordinate is zero. This eliminates one random variable.

may the fourth be with you... but leave the third alone!

Simulation with your sample-size of $n=10^7$ gave you an observed proportion $\hat p=0.4285833,$ so an approximate confidence interval for $p:=P(a^2<bc)$, with, say a $95\%$ "confidence level", is
$$\hat p\pm 1.96\,\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)\over n}=(0.4283, 0.4289)$$
Although $3/7=0.42857...$ does lie in this interval, the interval only esimates $p$ to about three digits of precision. Simulations using a larger sample-size suggest, with a very high degree of confidence/credibility, that $p\ne {3\over 7},$ the difference showing up in the fourth decimal place. Here's a picture of what I find with sample-size $10^{11}$:

The posterior distribution is $\text{Beta}(a,b)$, with $(a,b)=(n\hat p+{1\over 2}, n(1-\hat p)+{1\over 2}).$
The $100(1-\alpha)\%$ credibility interval is therefore $$(B_{\alpha\over 2},B_{1-{\alpha\over 2}})$$
where $B_q$ is the $q$-th quantile of the $\text{Beta}(a,b)$ distribution.
The $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence interval is $$\hat p\pm z_{\alpha\over 2}\,\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)\over n}$$
where $z_q$ is the $q$-th quantile of the standard normal distribution.
With the sample-size this large the various approaches to confidence/credibility intervals for $p$ should all give practically the same results (assuming a non-informative prior distribution in the Bayesian methods); e.g., they agree to about six decimal places for a $99.9\%$ confidence/credibility interval, namely
$$0.428790 \pm 0.000005 = (0.428785, 0.428795).$$
(I found no OEIS entries for decimal expansions in that interval, so I can't guess at the exact value.)

May I point out that taking a random point in the disk such that the distance to  the center is uniform on $[0.1]$ does not provide a uniform distribution in the disk?

@LetacGérard Yes, I agree. I used disk point picking.

@LetacGérard Agreed. Just to be clear: The simulation method I used for this answer is exactly the same as described in the question, just with a much larger sample-size.

There may be a question about the actual value of the probability, like using integration to find it.

@ТymaGaidash Of course I hope someone posts an exact answer to the OP's question "What is $P(a^2\lt bc)$?" (I hesitated to post the present "answer", as Monte Carlo simulation obviously cannot provide mathematical certainty -- not even for the title question "Is it 3/7?")

@r.e.s. I'm glad you decided to post your answer. I take your point about mathematical certainty, but I can sleep better now, knowing that the probability is probably (lol) not $\frac37$. That $7$ was bugging me :)

@r.e.s. If you have time and interest, here is another question that may benefit from  your simulation skills. Thanks.

@Dan Done
